# Why is William unaware of Katherine being alive?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-witch

In **The Witch**, William himself buried Katherine alive.

[image]

She sleeps beside him with blood dripping from her breast and he wakes up without any surprise.

[image]

Why is William unaware of Katherine being alive, after burying her?

Answer (score 1):

**He did not bury her alive.**

The mother was mourning the death of her young child and she could not let go of the child.

I understand your confusion, but here's what happened.

- Caleb (the kid) is dead
- Parents mourn and decides to bury him
- They dig a pit and mother couldn't let go of her son (screenshot #1) but eventually she had to let go
- Father buries his son

And the movie continues (screenshot #2)